# Access RowDataPacket without a variable specified

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to check if a user is in my database. The result has an value in the 
rowDataPacket. 0 if the user does not exist and 1 if he does exist. 
how do i access this value?

```
connection.query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = ?)", username, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(result[0]); // miserable attempts
        console.log(result[0].body);
        console.log(result[0].log);
```

which outputs:

RowDataPacket {
  'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = \'Test_user_name\')': 0 }
undefined
undefined

how can I access only the return value 0 or 1. (0 in the case above)

thanks in advance :)

EDIT: 
I was looking for a cleaner solution, but this works:

`var str = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
  var userExist = str[str.length - 2];`

when using stringify do not forget to install the module

installation:
`$ npm install json-stringify --save`

Documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword "AS" in your query, for example:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM smm.fb_users WHERE id = ?) AS cnt
```

Then you can access the value like this:

```
 console.log(results[0].cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access keys from fields,

```
fields[0].name
```

use the key to get value from the result

eg.

```
let existance = resultModel.result[0][resultModel.fields[0].name]
```

> or

you can use the **AS** keyword on the query to alias output key

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName="merlin" LIMIT 1) AS value;
```